# Permission for USB debugging is not being asked for by standard user accounts

Tags: windows, debugging, usb

While using an administrator account, every thing is fine, my phone asks for permission to allow debugging. But, for a standard User, the phone is not asking for it.

What is needed to be done?

- OS: Windows 7
- Phone: Realme 8